# laravel - what's the proper way to deal with calls towards multiple 3rd party APIs?

Tags: laravel-7, php-7.4

I have an app developed using `laravel 7`. This app gathers data from 3 different 3rd party APIs: api `A`, `B` and `C`. But now i'm stuck.

In the end all this APIs will insert/update data in the same table (`inventory`) but in the process API `A` needs a token and the other two are free(no authorization/token needed). For API `A` i'm storing the token in a table `api_a`.

Now the question is: should i have 3 different controllers (one for each API) and two models, one for `inventory` and one for `api_a`? But that would look ugly for some reason. Or is there a certain pattern that i should look into in order to solve this?

How should i deal with working with multiple 3rd party APIs ?

Comment: How do you decide which API to call?

Comment: @Norgul I'm running all of them every 15 minutes trough a scheduled task and then there's a button `Sync` which basically helps me sync the inventory whenever i need.

Comment: So it's not a controller per se, but a service class you call?

Comment: Well, i ended up creating a contract and all three apis implement it so i can end up with one simple structure for all three calls since they end up updating the same table. Not sure if that's called a service tho? :-s (i'm kinda new to patterns - end even newer to laravel)

Comment: If you already did that, it is a good design. Controller purpose is to be hit from the outside world (someone going on your page/API and calling `/something/something` route). If you are calling these in the background, a simple contract with 3 separate classes is what I'd go for as well.

Comment: And how would you deal with having the `Sync` button? For that i have a controller InventoryController which has a method called sync which uses the binded contract `public function sync(InventoryResourceContract $inventoryResource){ ...}` is this oky or should i do something fancier? :-?

Comment: Why do you have a button if you have a scheduled task already?

Comment: because sometimes i need to sync it in between those tasks. For example when a customer calls me and asks if i have x amount of foo available. I don't know, call it fear of letting my customers down i guess? ^.^

Comment: I mean, does sync button do the same thing as the scheduled task?

Comment: Hmm, kind of? except for the fact that at the end i get a nice little pop-up with real time inventory :D (each sync takes aroung 5 seconds to complete)

Comment: Unless the API's you are communicating with have some sort of callbacks or socket communication, I guess there is no smarter way to do this to have the fresh data at a tip of your fingers

Comment: I finally can sleep over this #-o. I read so many articles on best practices but there's not much on this topic that i could find. Thank you so much! :D O and btw, do you know any good articles/books on topics like this (best implementation practices or something like that) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218416/discussion-between-emma-and-norgul).